# What does the "got " mean here

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw these sentences in an online lecture and get confused about the usage of "got". Is the use of "got" correct here?

1. > He got me to sell my old car at a low price.
2. > My mother got me to cook dinner for her.

Answer (score 2):

[merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get) gives this definition:

> **9 :**  to prevail on **:**  cause **finally *got* them to tidy up their room**

Therefore, if "My mother got me to cook dinner for her", that means that she prevailed on me to do it.  In plain English, she *made* me do it or she *convinced* me to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "got" you can use "made". He made me sell my old car at a low price.
My mother made me cook dinner for her. - Your question is a question for the dictionary.

See Oald get, number 13 [Link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)